# when to enable forms authentication sliding expiration

Tags: asp.net, ssl, forms-authentication

I've read in MSDN that when SSL is not activated for your website , set slidingExpiration as false. this is to limit the time that a hijacker could use the stolen authcookie .

but this makes no sense . when there is no SSL then the hacker could take the credentials itself and use them . why should he/she steal the cookie when he/she has access to username/password ?

I want to say that slidingExpiration has no relation to enabledSSL .

Answer (score 1):

> why should he/she steal the cookie when he/she has access to username/password ?

What makes you think that he has access to the username/password? **Only** the username is present inside the encrypted forms authentication cookie. So what he steals is the cookie, not the username or password. He cannot decrypt it (unless he uses brute force) so he cannot fetch the original username nor he can change this username. Since the password is not even present in this cookie he cannot have the password. So if this cookie has sliding expiration activated he could use it as long as it is valid.

But in general if you care about security you should always use SSL.

Comment: that's right . cookie only contains username and hacker can use the cookie as far as cookie is valid ( setting slidingExpiration as false works great here ) but I want to say that without SSL when user tries to login his credentials is sent in plain text so hacker could use these instead of stealing the resulted auth cookie

Comment: Correct, you are absolutely right. Username and password are sent as plain text when the user is logging in. I thought you were asking about the authentication cookie.